# PHP Pages on My Website Are Showing Up Blank

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache2, debian

I have searched all over the forums and cannot find a answer to my problem. I have tried to install some CMS that use PHP to my website and all of them are showing up blank. I have enabled error reporting in the php.ini and no erros where shown. I am using Debian 7 to run my server. I have installed apache2, mysql-server, and, php5, php5-mysql, and libapache2-mod-php5. The Configuration File For PHP is accessible here: http://info.ozooma.net/. The CMS Im Currently Using Is Joomla and is accessible here: http://www.ozooma.net/. Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: White Screen of Death. You have a server error - look at your server logs.

Comment: Check your web server's logs.

Comment: Where can i access the server log at?

Comment: Server shows - 500 Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get this issue a few times a year.

Here is my debug steps:

1. Make sure apache is running

   ```
   ps ax | grep httpd | grep -v grep
   ```

   and that its listening on port 80 for http:

   ```
   netstat -l | grep http
   ```
2. add a index.html to the root dir and check that
3. add index.php with

That will normally tell you where its broken up at.

Since your using a CMS, make sure your URL rewrite mod is enabled, and that your config is allowing overrides.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a PHP or Apache error.

Check the apache logs, according to your PHP info it is located at: /var/log/apache2

Comment: Here is the log file. I do not know what is wrong with my server still. http://www.ozooma.net/tpm1/log1.log

Comment: You have some permission errors. You need to chmod your php files to 0644.

Comment: What command do i use to chmod the whole directory /var/www/?

Comment: This should work `chmod -R /var/www 0777` - This will chmod it to 0777 which will work as long as you are not running SuPHP (cPanel does by default)

Answer (score 0):

Verify a recent version of Joomla (2.5 or 3.x) was installed properly since you're running PHP 5.4.  Older versions of Joomla wouldn't run right with PHP 5.4.

Comment: I am using Joomla 3.2.0

Comment: So would it be better to go to a older version of PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Your server Cause of HTTP 500 Errors

The 500 Internal Server Error is a very general HTTP status code that means something has gone wrong on the web site's server but the server could not be more specific on what the exact problem is.

Most of the time, "gone wrong" means an issue with the page or site's programming, nothing you have anything to do with.

Note: More specific information about the cause of a particular HTTP 500 error is often provided when it occurs on a server using Microsoft IIS software. Look for numbers after 500 as in HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error which means Configuration data is invalid.

Ref: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/500servererror.htm